# Trigger GitLab Build with Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to trigger a GitLab build using Python Requests.  Normally one can kick off a build with a `curl` command.

Example curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
  -F token=TOKEN \
  -F ref=master \
  -F "variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]=true" \
  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline
```

I can get this working using the `sh` module but I'd prefer using `requests`.  I've tried variations with the following:

```
data = {
    'token': token,
    'ref': master,
    'variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]': str(uploadS3),
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
result = requests.post(_trigger_url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

I tried with and without the `headers` param.  I've also tried passing the `data` dict using `params`, `json`, `files`, and `data`. All keep coming back with 400 or 404 errors.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't send the `Content-Type: "application/json"` header as part of your request, and you should only need form encoding, so just pass your `data` dict as the `data` argument.

Here's a request to my Gitlab instance that succeeds and triggers a build of my project's master branch.

```
rsp = requests.post('https://gitlab.instance/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/trigger/pipeline',
          data={'token': '125fdsfdf1ab3631d2423434347643', 'ref': 'master'})
```

Here's the output if I inspect my `rsp` object in `ipython:

```
In [3]: rsp
Out[3]: <Response [201]>
```

You should also be able to trigger the pipeline by sending a `POST` and including the `token` and `ref` in the URL itself.

```
rsp = requests.post('https://gitlab.instance/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/trigger/pipeline?token=TOKEN&ref=master')
```

---

If I pass the `Content-Type: "application/json"` header, Gitlab responds with an HTTP/400 error.

Comment: So what are you passing to headers? When I take the headers argument out completely I get 404 errors.

Comment: @JaySoyer I don't explicitly pass any headers - that line I showed is the only thing I executed to trigger a build (besides `import requests`). The automatic headers included in my request are: `{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '47', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`.

Comment: In your example line, you are explicitly passing a header...which is why I asked.  My automatic header looks the same except i'm using python-requests 2.18.3.

Comment: @JaySoyer sorry, copied the wrong piece of code from my window. Updated my code snippet.

Comment: Well, updated to 2.18.4 and matched exactly what you are doing.  Still getting 404.  Think I'm missing something.

Comment: @JaySoyer - try the last portion of my answer - I just updated with an alternative request style (putting `token` and `ref` into the URL as a query string. I executed that directly and had it succeed. I can also get builds to trigger with v2.17.x of Requests, so it doesn't seem to be a version problem, at least. If you still get errors, does accessing the `text` property of the response object return anything?

Comment: Problem was a duh moment for me.  Turns out the issue was with my trigger url.  I was storing it in a variable and there was a space at the very end of it.  Apparently this breaks `requests` but does not break `sh.curl()`.  Both your original version and edited version work for me now.  Thanx for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is incomplete as it does not deal with the part that makes this complex that is passing trough variables.

To pass variables around with requests using json data one needs to pass the data in the following structure

```
data = {
    'token': token,
    'ref': master,
    'variables': [{"key": "UPLOAD_TO_S3", "value": True}, {"key": "S3_SERVER", "value": "https://mys3.example.com"}],
}

result = requests.post(_trigger_url, json=data)
```

Answer (score 3):

The first answer doesn't address the "variables" part. The second answer didn't work for me. Here's what I ended up with working:

```py
variables = {
    "UPLOAD_TO_S3": True,
    "S3_SERVER": "https://mys3.example.com"
}

data = {
    "token": token,
    "ref": ref_name,
    "variables": variables
}

res = requests.post(pipeline_trigger, json=data)
```